# Chat keeps telling me I need 20 reputation points to talk there

Tags: bug, reputation, chat, privileges, 404-not-found

I [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34895126/1521227) a few days ago and another user and I got into discussion in the comments. We then transferred this communication to the chat, but it seems that it no longer exists. I assume that it got cleaned up due to inactivity.

So far everything's fine.

When [opening the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101170/discussion-between-daimto-and-spontifixus) however the site displays a banner telling me I need at least 20 reputation to talk there:

[image]

I think I am well over that limit here on StackOverflow and while the "Page not found" error seems to be fine, the reputation limit banner is a bug in my opinion.

**UPDATE:** I just tried to find out whether I am logged in on chat. It says "Spontifixus" in the header, but still shows the not enough rep warning:

[image]

**UPDATE2:** Both screenshots were made on a Windows 8.1 machine. The first screenshot was taken using Chrome 48.0.2564.97, with some ad-blocking plugins installed. The second screenshot was taken using IE 11.09600.17842 using no plugins.

Comment: He :) I'm amazed that you can get past the excruciating "page not found" so easily and then trip over a banner which is clearly just a failure caused by a failure :)

Comment: It's strange that you are getting a *page not found*! Am able to see the transcript alright, although the last message does say that *this room is deleted*, but the room does open.

Comment: "Page not found" here too... (*and* the reputation message, which is as nonsensical for me as it is for the OP)

Comment: I can open the chat page now without error. Fixed?

Comment: @Abhitalks With >= 10.000 rep I guess you see deleted rooms - as you can see deleted questions and answers, too...

Comment: @BobJarvis I guess the same (>= 10.000 rep) applies to you, too. Not fixed for me.

Comment: @Spontifixus - I agree, that seems to be the case. I'd think that a more appropriate response than "Page not found" could be produced.

Comment: @Abhitalks since you have 10k+ on the chat network, you can see deleted/frozen rooms

Comment: I get proper "Page not found", no error about reputation though, at 6k rep. Are you logged in to chat? Chat uses a separate login session, I've been logged out of chat several times randomly, which can easily lead to this message if it happens. Your [chat page](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1521227/spontifixus?tab=general) says "last seen 3d ago". Then again, your screenshot shows your username behind the banner...

Comment: I am still seeing both the page-not-found and the reputation banner.

Comment: Could you be accidentally and temporarily signed out?

Comment: Are you logged in to chat?

Comment: Are you using HTTPS Everywhere by chance? That's been known to cause issues with chat, leading to strange cases like this.

Comment: @KevinBrown No, I don't

Comment: @Oded please see my update.

Comment: What browser and OS are you using (with versions please)? Any add-ons/plugins?

Comment: @Oded please see my updated question